# React Native app crashing on launch under android

Tags: android, react-native

```
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mybundle.status, PID: 27255
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: "Status" has not been registered. This can happen if:
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes, stack:
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: invariant@1:63232
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: runApplication@1:257741
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: __callFunction@1:71995
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous@1:70504
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: __guard@1:71442
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1:70462
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime: 
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
08-08 15:25:56.464 27255 27309 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Logcat output above

App was launched using `npm run android -- --mode=Release`, so I would not expect metro needs to be running. What do I need to look for, to find which module isn't being loaded?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Status is not registered. If you are using Expo, try to build your application and install in on your emulator / physical device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).